# How to conditionally concatenate sub ranges into different strings in vba for each loop

Tags: vba

I have a list of sales persons and the items they sell. 1 sales person sells n items. I need to display a summarised list of 1 sales person per row and concatenate all the items they sell in the next cell of same row separated by commas.

[image: Input]

I first create a range containing unique sales persons,
Then loop through the range containing sales persons with a for each loop, 
For each occurrence of a sales in this range, I concatenate the item sold into a temp variable

This is my code so far:

```
i = 2 ' Depending on my reports sheet
For Each salesPerson In salesPersons
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).range(salesPerson.Offset(0, 1).Address).Copy_ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(2).range("F" & i)
    items = items & "," & ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).range(salesPerson.Offset(0, 1).Address)
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(2).range("G" & i).Value = items
    i = i + 1
Next salesPerson
```

[image]

I expect to have a list of unique sales persons and the items they sell concatenated in the cell next to it, but I get a kinda Pascal's triangle display. Maybe I need another inner loop. Not sure how to proceed.
Please any help would be very much appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the layout of your data? What does the range `salesPersons` contain? A unique list of salesPerson names? If so, where is the list of the corresponding items? There are a few ways to tackle your problem, but it would help to get an idea of the data layout.

Comment: Hi, thanks for response. salesPersons contain all sales personel. items has a list of all items sold by them. But it is required to display one sales person and next to it have a concatenation of the items they sold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT (based on additional information in the comments)

You have a few options when you want to add more than one element in the `Value` item of the dictionary. You can use custom made objects, arrays, or nested dictionaries. I tend to use nested dictionaries because they give a JSON-like feel to my in-memory collection. Additionally, they don't have the extra work and overhead of building a class, and they don't require us to remember positions like an array would.

See the below code and test it in your application. An important note: I noticed that each salesperson only had one city, so I didn't make changes to the city field once it was populated. If this isn't the case, then you'll have to amend the code to meet the needs.

```
Sub ConcatenateItems()
    Dim salesPersons As Range
    Dim slsPerson As Range
    Dim oDictionary As Object
    Dim tmpItems As String
    Dim oTmpDict As Object

    'The range holding the salespeople (change this to your range)
    Set salesPersons = Range("A2:A18")

    'Dictionary object to hold unique salesperson names and their list of items
    Set oDictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    For Each slsPerson In salesPersons
        'Check if we've already added this salesperson
        If oDictionary.exists(slsPerson.Value) Then
            'Get the currently stored items string
            tmpItems = oDictionary(slsPerson.Value)("Items")

            ''''''''''''''''''''
            ' IMPORTANT NOTE:
            ' In the example, each salesperson only had one city,
            ' so I do not update the city with each iteration.
            ' Instead, I only update the items and assume the city
            ' is correct from a prior iteration.
            ''''''''''''''''''''

            'Update the items string with the new item
            tmpItems = tmpItems & ", " & slsPerson.Offset(, 1).Value

            'Replace the items string with the update version
            oDictionary(slsPerson.Value)("Items") = tmpItems
        Else
            'Salesperson not yet added

            'Create a temp dictionary with two keys, 'Items' and 'City'
            Set oTmpDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
            oTmpDict.Add "Items", slsPerson.Offset(, 1).Value
            oTmpDict.Add "City", slsPerson.Offset(, 2).Value

            oDictionary.Add slsPerson.Value, oTmpDict
        End If
    Next slsPerson

    'Once the dictionary has been fully populated in memory, place it wherever you'd like

    Dim rngDestination As Range

    Set rngDestination = Sheet2.Range("A1")

    For Each oKey In oDictionary
        'Put salesperson name in rngDestination
        rngDestination.Value = oKey

        'Put items list in the cell to the left
        rngDestination.Offset(, 1).Value = oDictionary(oKey)("Items")
        rngDestination.Offset(, 2).Value = oDictionary(oKey)("City")

        'Set rngDestination to the next cell down for the following iteration
        Set rngDestination = rngDestination.Offset(1)
    Next oKey

End Sub
```

---

When it comes to manipulations like these, I tend to do them in-memory and then put the analyzed information into the spreadsheet all at once. In this case, since you are dealing with unique salesperson names (I'm assuming they are unique for the purpose of grouping), I use a dictionary object. Try to follow the code and adapt it to your needs, and write back if you have any issues or questions.

```
Sub ConcatenateItems()
    Dim salesPersons As Range
    Dim slsPerson As Range
    Dim oDictionary As Object
    Dim tmpItems As String


    'The range holding the salespeople (change this to your range)
    Set salesPersons = Range("A2:A17")

    'Dictionary object to hold unique salesperson names and their list of items
    Set oDictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    For Each slsPerson In salesPersons
        'Check if we've already added this salesperson
        If oDictionary.exists(slsPerson.Value) Then
            'Get the currently stored items string
            tmpItems = oDictionary(slsPerson.Value)

            'Update the items string with the new item
            tmpItems = tmpItems & ", " & slsPerson.Offset(, 1).Value

            'Replace the items string with the update version
            oDictionary(slsPerson.Value) = tmpItems
        Else
            'Salesperson not yet added
            oDictionary.Add slsPerson.Value, slsPerson.Offset(, 1).Value
        End If
    Next slsPerson

    'Once the dictionary has been fully populated in memory, place it wherever you'd like

    Dim rngDestination As Range

    Set rngDestination = Sheet2.Range("A1")

    For Each oKey In oDictionary
        'Put salesperson name in rngDestination
        rngDestination.Value = oKey

        'Put items list in the cell to the left
        rngDestination.Offset(, 1).Value = oDictionary(oKey)

        'Set rngDestination to the next cell down for the following iteration
        Set rngDestination = rngDestination.Offset(1)
    Next oKey

End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect Answer! I will then make the range dynamic by means of "UsedRange" in  order to accept inputs of any number of tupples.

Comment: @KingSufu Great to hear. One thing to keep in mind with `.UsedRange` is that it is not constrained to a single column. So, for example if Salesperson Name is `A1:A17` and the items are in `B1:B17`, `.UsedRange` will return `A1:B17`. When you enter into your `For Each slsPerson` loop, it will go through all cells of BOTH columns. Be careful with that.

Comment: Hello @user3561813 I have read the docs for vba Dictionary Object but can find a way to copy other info along the above. The Object offers key value pairs. What if I have to display other info along the above e.g. the sales person town? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: @KingSufu You have the option of adding other `Object` subclasses in the `Value` field of the dictionary. So, in your case, you can add an array as the Value, or another `Dictionary` object. It's hard to be more precise without knowing the specifics of your need.

Comment: Hello @user3561813 Please look at the clarifications pointed to by http://www.betterlearnit.com/2017/04/excel-vba-help.html Thank you

Comment: @KingSufu I made an edit to my original post. Please review it and let me know if it fills the requirements. Also let me know if you have any questions about the code.

Comment: Hello @user3561813 your additional edits meet the exact requirements and your observation about the sales Persons towns is accurate too. I was already working on using a custom class and build objects from it but the nested Dictionaries code you provided avoid so many overheads and obfuscation. I resorted to it and added other columns to my output sheet. Thanks imensely

Comment: @KingSufu No Problem!